# scala - javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, scala, jakarta-mail

my aim is to send a dataframe through Email. below is my piece of code:

```
import javax.mail._
import javax.mail.internet._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object EmailAlert {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("E-mail Alert").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
var bodyText = "Test mail"

// Set up the mail object
val properties = System.getProperties
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", "********");
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", "********");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587")
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
val session = Session.getInstance(properties)
val message = new MimeMessage(session)

def getPasswordAuthentication(username:String, password:String):Authenticator=
{
  new Authenticator(){
    override def getPasswordAuthentication():PasswordAuthentication = {
      new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }}
}

// Set the from, to, subject, body text
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@****.com"))
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "ajayv@****.com")
message.setSubject("Count of DeviceIDs we are sent daily")
message.setText(bodyText)

// And send it
Transport.send(message)
  }
}
```

but i get the below error when i execute the code:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

what am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to pass Authentication to the session which is what i am missed, Below code worked for me :

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("E-mail Alert").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
var bodyText = "Test mail"
val username = "*****************"
val password = "************************"
val smtpHost = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

// Set up the mail object
val properties = System.getProperties
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost)
properties.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587")
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

val auth:Authenticator = new Authenticator() {
  override def getPasswordAuthentication = new
      PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
}

val session = Session.getInstance(properties,auth)
val message = new MimeMessage(session)

// Set the from, to, subject, body text
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@*****.com"))
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, "ajayv@****.com")
message.setSubject("Count of DeviceIDs we are sent daily")
message.setText(bodyText)

// And send it
Transport.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the Authenticator (which isn't being used at all) and the `mail.smtp.user`, `mail.smtp.password`, and `mail.smtp.auth` properties, then call the [Transport.send method that takes a user name and password](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).  If it still doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: Why did you say they are not used at all, if so what can i make them to use

Comment: As far as I can tell (and I'm not a Scala expert), the Authenticator you're declaring is never being used.  Normally it would be passed to the Session.getInstance method.  Anyway, do what I said; [you don't need the Authenticator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).